# Cannot connect to WPA2/WPA Enterprise (PEAP and MSCHAP)

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04

I cannot connect to my campus Wi-Fi connection through Ubuntu 13.04 but I can do the same through Windows.

```
[ 1293.944518] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1a:1e:d5:f0:30
[ 1293.953216] wlan0: send auth to 00:1a:1e:d5:f0:30 (try 1/3)
[ 1294.154557] wlan0: send auth to 00:1a:1e:d5:f0:30 (try 2/3)
[ 1294.358428] wlan0: send auth to 00:1a:1e:d5:f0:30 (try 3/3)
[ 1294.562357] wlan0: authentication with 00:1a:1e:d5:f0:30 timed out
```

The same thing keeps occurring.

Comment: I am using the same authentication; So be sure that you have modified the network settings for the correct network, set authentication to the correct one and be sure you don't need any Domain in front of your username: DOMAIN\Username

Comment: Also make sure to use the correct Authentication and Phase 2 Authentication settings. Took me a while to figure that out. If the campus network you are writing about happens to be eduroam, maybe this guide can help: http://www.jku.at/content/e213/e174/e167/e75061/e74996/e74892/e98273/

Comment: Looks like I have the same problem. It finds the networks but cannot authenticate after the update to 13.04... I have a Broadcom DW1501 adapter

Comment: Look here
http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap/354986#354986

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I found a solution in this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476 (post 19)

> Removing "system-ca-certs=true" from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections may solve your problem.

Comment: Setting it to false didn't seem to help, but removing the entry solved the issue :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

1. Click on the Wi-Fi icon on the rigth corner and click "Edit Connections..."
2. Select your Wi-Fi network (eduroam) and click "Edit"
3. Click "Wi-Fi Security" tab
4. Set Authentication to "Protected EAP (PEAP)"
5. Tick "No CA certificate is required"
6. Set PEAP Version to "Automatic"
7. Set Inner Authentication to "MSCHAPv2"
8. Type your username and password
9. Click "Save"

You should be able to connect now. Editing the file in system-connections folder did not work for me.

Comment: this worked for me on 17.04

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that there aren't any lines like `system-ca-certs=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<SSID>`, so I resolved in this way:

1. Turn off WiFi
2. Add on a new line `system-ca-certs=false`
3. Turn on WiFi (the line will be deleted automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem connecting to my university wifi. If disabling system-ca-certs doesn't work for you, try downgrading wpasupplicant.

If ur on ubuntu, you can downgrade to wpasupplicant 2.9.0 build 1 using:

```
sudo cat <<'EOF' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish.list
     deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted universe multiverse
     deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted universe multiverse
     deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-security main restricted universe multiverse
     EOF
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y --allow-downgrades install wpasupplicant=2:2.9.0-21build1
sudo apt-mark hold wpasupplicant
```

If this works for u, all credits go to my seniors who posted this on our Foss club discord server.