# Can't connect to Wireless 13.10

Tags: networking, drivers, 13.10, ath9k

I am having problems with my wireless connection using ath9k, I cannot connect to any wireless network. I can connect to the wireless network fine on windows 8.1 but when using ubuntu gnome I have no luck.

**Any Help Appreciated.**

OS: Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

What has been tried so far:

`sudo modprobe -r ath9k`

`sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1`

`sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac`

`echo "blacklist brcmsmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Wireless Card: TP Link TL-WDN3800

```
*************** info trace ***************

***** uname -a *****

Linux jamie 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64     x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

***** lsb_release *****

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy

***** lspci *****

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter     [168c:0030] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:3116]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: r8169

***** lsusb *****

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 15d9:0a4d Trust International B.V. Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:3431  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

***** PCMCIA Card Info *****


***** iwconfig *****

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off


***** rfkill *****

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

***** lsmod *****

brcmsmac              562767  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   46670  1 brcmsmac
ath9k                 151173  0 
ath9k_common           13859  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              444645  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    23827  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              596969  2 ath9k,brcmsmac
cfg80211              479757  4 ath,ath9k,brcmsmac,mac80211

***** nm-tool *****

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        94:DE:80:78:51:14

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        A0:F3:C1:24:C5:87

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    BTWiFi-with-FON: Infra, 02:22:69:6B:FF:48, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57
    BTWiFi:          Infra, 02:22:69:6B:FF:4B, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65
    TalkTalk:        Infra, 20:F3:A3:FE:0D:16, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 82 WPA WPA2
    BTHomeHub2-TMW4: Infra, 00:22:69:6B:FF:4A, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64 WPA WPA2
    virginmedia2978209: Infra, 74:44:01:F3:23:C0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2



***** NetworkManager.state *****
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

***** NetworkManager.conf *****

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

***** interfaces *****

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

***** iwlist *****

wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 20:F3:A3:FE:0D:16
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"TalkTalk"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000009e93517f
                Extra: Last beacon: 1156ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000854616C6B54616C6B
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown:     2D1A0E181EFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B070000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C330E181EFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C340B070000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD0600E04C020160
                IE: Unknown: DD0E0050F204104A0001101044000102
      Cell 02 - Address: 74:44:01:F3:23:C0
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"virginmedia2978209"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000011cc720019c
                Extra: Last beacon: 1172ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 001276697267696E6D6564696132393738323039
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180203F02C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00


***** resolv.conf *****


***** blacklist *****
```

Output for lsmod | grep -E 'ath|brcmsmac'

```
** lsmod | grep -E 'ath|brcmsmac' **

ath9k                 151173  0 
ath9k_common           13859  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              444645  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    23827  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              596969  1 ath9k
cfg80211              479757  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
```

Output for dmesg | grep -E 'cfg|ath|wlan'

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/6698611/

Comment: Everything in those outputs seems fine. What **exactly** are you experiencing? Can you see a list of wireless networks when you click on the wireless symbol on the top right? Can you click and connect to your desired network? Do you enter the password correctly if it asks you for one? Or does it repeatedly ask you for a password even after you enter it correctly? Or do you connect successfully, but can't access the internet? What exactly are you facing?

Comment: I can see wireless networks, I click to connect enter a password and it does not connect. I'm 100% certain the password is correct.  It does not repeatedly ask me for a password, It does not connect at all, says "connecting" then nothing. I also tried connection to a wifi hotspot on a phone and the same thing happened.

Comment: Try executing `sudo modprobe -r ath9k`, then `sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1`, then try to connect.

Comment: Ok I will test this now, may take 10 minutes for me to reply, have to reboot etc.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say thanks for the help so far. I executed the commands above but still cannot connect.

Comment: Oh, I think I've spotted the issue. Check out my answer.

Comment: Take a look a this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285234/cannot-connect-to-wpa2-wpa-enterprise-peap-and-mschap

Answer (score 0):

Execute:

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac
```

Then try to connect. That should work.

If it does (or even if it doesn't) work, execute the following:

```
echo "blacklist brcmsmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, going to try this and will post the result when I finish.

Comment: I executed the first command then tried to connect, no luck. executed the second command rebooted but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Oh man. I'm out of ideas. Edit your question to include what you did so far (so others don't miss anything). Also, include the output of `lsmod | grep -E 'ath|brcmsmac'` and `dmesg | grep -E 'cfg|ath|wlan'`. This should help others in troubleshooting. If the output of the second command is huge, paste it in http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
rfkill list all
```

in the terminal. It will bring up something that looks like this

> `0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>       Soft blocked: yes
>       Hard blocked: no
>   1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
>       Soft blocked: no
>       Hard blocked: no

If any of them come back saying yes use`rfkill unblock all`
Hopefully this fixes the issue