# Unable to connect to my college WPA enterprise network

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager, wpa2

I moved from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 14.04 last week. I could able to connect to my Internet from my home. But, when I tried to connect to college network, I'm repeatedly asked for either Certificate and Password.

I've tried all the solutions mentioned in the thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1104476 .

Issues: First of all, I don't have an entry `"system-ca-certs=true"` in my connection file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<my college network>` to remove. Even I tried adding and removing the same with false. And restarted my network-manager and system, But, it didn't help me. I've trying to resolve this from the last two weeks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to WPA2/WPA Enterprise (PEAP and MSCHAP)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285234/cannot-connect-to-wpa2-wpa-enterprise-peap-and-mschap)

Comment: **Note to CVers:** The possible dupe does not provide an answer to this question according to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my college network. For some reasons Ubuntu could not locate the appropriate certificate by itself.
The best solution is to find in your college website which certificate is requested. Then when the network request it, you should navigate within your browser settings and find the suitable certificate. In my case it was in user/.Firefox/authenticate or something similar.
I'm writing from my phone so cannot check. Sorry