# Ubuntu can't connect to Sophos Access Point

Tags: wireless, 20.04, authentication

I cannot connect to Sophos Access Point, it's look like it not even there. My conf:

[image]

Network logs:

> out 06 11:49:54 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7931] device
> (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'XXXXX' has security, and
> secrets exist. No new secrets needed. out 06 11:49:54 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7931] Config: added 'ssid' value
> 'XXXXXX' out 06 11:49:54 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7932]
> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1' out 06 11:49:54 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7932] Config: added 'freq_list' value
> '2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
> 2484' out 06 11:49:54 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7932]
> Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300' out 06 11:49:54
> pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7932] Config: added 'key_mgmt'
> value 'WPA-EAP' out 06 11:49:54 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]:
> [1601981394.7932] Config: added 'password' value '' out 06 11:49:54
> pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7932] Config: added 'eap'
> value 'PWD' out 06 11:49:54 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]:
> [1601981394.7932] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266' out 06
> 11:49:54 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7933] Config: added
> 'identity' value 'username' out 06 11:49:54 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981394.7933] Config: added
> 'proactive_key_caching' value '1' out 06 11:49:55 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981395.8011] device (wlp2s0): supplicant
> interface state: disconnected -> scanning out 06 11:49:58 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981398.5005] device (wlp2s0): supplicant
> interface state: scanning -> authenticating out 06 11:49:58 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981398.5044] device (wlp2s0): supplicant
> interface state: authenticating -> associating out 06 11:49:58 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981398.5116] device (wlp2s0): supplicant
> interface state: associating -> associated out 06 11:49:58 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981398.6215]
> sup-iface[0x563467f10a30,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 23)
> out 06 11:49:58 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981398.6267] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected out
> 06 11:49:58 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981398.7267] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning out 06
> 11:50:11 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981411.4617] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating out
> 06 11:50:11 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981411.4834] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
> out 06 11:50:11 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981411.4839] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated out 06
> 11:50:11 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981411.5862]
> sup-iface[0x563467f10a30,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 23)
> out 06 11:50:11 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981411.5916] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected out
> 06 11:50:11 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981411.6918] device
> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning out 06
> 11:50:19 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981419.1052] connectivity:
> (wlp2s0) timed out out 06 11:50:20 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]:
> [1601981420.1007] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took
> too long out 06 11:50:20 pl1772 NetworkManager[646]: [1601981420.1008]
> device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none',
> sys-iface-state: 'managed') out 06 11:50:20 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981420.1053] device (wlp2s0): Activation:
> (wifi) asking for new secrets out 06 11:50:48 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981448.7335] device (wlp2s0): supplicant
> interface state: scanning -> inactive out 06 11:50:55 pl1772
> NetworkManager[646]: [1601981455.1050] connectivity: (enx1065300844d2)
> timed out

Comment: In my opinion there is not enough signal

Comment: the access point is very near me, 1 meter max

Comment: This solved my problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/285234/cannot-connect-to-wpa2-wpa-enterprise-peap-and-mschap Thanks