# Connect to my College's WPA from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, network-manager, password, security

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and am running it on a Sony Vaio VGN-CR12OE. It is the only operating system. I am trying to connect to my college's WPA WiFi. My settings for this WiFi connection are as follows:

```
Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
Anonymous identity: <I've been leaving this field blank>
CA certificate: AddTrust_External_Root.crt <see below fixes I have already tried>
PEAP version: Automatic
Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2
Username: <my username>
Password: <my password>
```

Warns me that I haven't attached a CA certificate
Keeps warning that I don't have one, regardless of whether I check "don't warn me again" and click "ignore".
I give CA certificate from `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt`
Stops warning me that I don't have CA certificate

When I try to connect, it keeps prompting for password
I tried checking the box found at WiFi menu > Edit Connections > "General" tab > "All users may connect to this network"
Still keeps prompting for password

Comment: This bug was marked fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1104476 so updating to the latest version should fix this without manual editing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I had already tried setting system-ca-certs=false before, and it didn't help, even when I did recreate the connection. As to your second comment, what exactly needs the updating, and how do I do this updating?

Comment: The `network-manager-applet` package needs updating. It should be in version `0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3` or higher. But if `system-ca-certs=false` didn't help, this might not either.

Comment: I'd like to try setting system-ca-certs=false one more time, in case I happened to do it wrongly last time. In the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MYCONNECTION file, where should I add that line? there is no line in there already that says "system-ca-certs=true", so I don't know where to add that line.

Comment: If you have added a CA certificate, that line wouldn't appear or apply. Did you create the connection with the CA certificate this time?

Comment: No, this time, I have not added a CA certificate, but the line still has not appeared. Would you like me to paste what is in the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MYCONNECTION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix that I finally found is the answer in this thread: [How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap). I will sum it up here.

All I did was add the `auth-alg=open` to the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MYCONNECTION`, at the bottom of the `[802-11-wireless-security]` section of the document. I hope this helps more people than just me.