# cannot connect school WiFi on 14.10

Tags: wireless, 14.10

I just install Ubuntu 14.10 and wanna connect to school WiFi(wpa2 enterprise/peap/mschapv2), but failed. According to forum solution, I need to delete a line called `system-ca-certs=true`. But I even cannot find it in that file. Anyone has idea?

The solution for the low version [How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap)

I put my file below, clearly, no line related to "system-ca-certs"

```
[connection]
id=***
uuid=672b112a-ed80-4d76-9cb9-9f1435919b78
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=***
mode=infrastructure
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=jz1958
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password-flags=1
```

Comment: Can you please link the forum post and which file(s) you're supposed edit?

Comment: Hi David, this link is what I've found to solve my problem, but it seems that version is lower than 14.10, http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap. In 14.10 when I open my connection file, which shows below:

Comment: [connection]
id=***
uuid=672b112a-ed80-4d76-9cb9-9f1435919b78
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=***
mode=infrastructure
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=jz1958
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password-flags=1

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi David, above is what my situation's. I could not be able to find that line "system-ca-cert=true" in the file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add additional info. It's much harder to go through all the comments to find it. Also don't put file listings in the comments. They're usually difficult to read without line breaks.

Comment: That bug was fixed after 14.04, so it shouldn't be the problem if you have an updated system.

Comment: So, what should I do to connect to the wifi? I could successfully connect to the home router using WAP2 personal. @muru

Comment: I suggest going to your school's IT department or help desk. They should know about their onw network's quirks ans what not.

Comment: They said maybe ubuntu14.10 doesn't support full version of wpa2 enterprise.

Comment: You might want to check user250563 answer on the flagged duplicate.