# can't get wireless up on corporate network

Tags: wireless

I'm relatively new to linux/ubuntu. I'm trying to connect my laptop to my work wireless and have been unsuccessful; it just keeps asking for the name and password over and over. I had the same problem when I was using windows 7 and was able to get it it working by installing Cisco peap module which added "cisco" peap as an authentication option in the wireless settings. I looked around and was unable to find that for linux. Does anyone know a fix or way around this? Lan works fine as does connecting to open wifi.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please click the Network Manager icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Under Wi-Fi Security, select 'WPA & WPA2 Enterprise.' There, you may select Protected EAP (PEAP). Fill in your details and connect.

Comment: Iv'e done that without success

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap

Comment: How do I find this file? I'm used to windows here:)

Comment: You will edit the file; from a terminal: `gksudo gedit  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<your_network>` Of course, substitute the actual name of the network you are attempting to connect to. Remove the line in question; save and close the text editor. Restart Network Manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`. Now can you connect?

Comment: I don't see "system-ca-cert=true" in the list