# Cannot connect Kubuntu 18.04 to Enterprise WPA2 PEAP authentication

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I'm having trouble connecting to my institution's wifi on Kubuntu 18.04. The laptop I'm using can connect just fine when using Windows 10. I can also connect using my username and password on my Android device. The android settings are EAP = PEAP, Phase 2 = "none" and no CA Certificate.

However on linux it doesn't work. I have looked through a lot of other posts and have not been successful. Thus far I have tried editing `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` to remove the line `system-ca-cert=true` as mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c) but this line didn't exist to begin with, and tried to modify the file as described in the answer below the first, but my config file looks very different than his. I tried to make the appropriate changes but no connection would be made. I also tried looking through [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929680/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap-network) but was unable to get things working.

When I try to connect here is the info from:

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep Network`

```
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8761] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'XXXX' (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8764] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="XXXXXXXXX" name="XXXXX" pid=1176 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8769] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8773] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8788] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8794] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'XXXXXX' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul  9 13:02:05 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166525.8794] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3536] settings-connection[0xXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]: write: successfully updated (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,"XXXX")), connection was modified in the process
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3578] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3584] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3589] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'XXXX' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3590] Config: added 'ssid' value 'XXXX'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3590] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3590] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3591] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3591] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3591] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3591] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3591] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3591] Config: added 'identity' value 'XXXX'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3592] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3691] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.3864] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.4295] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <warn>  [1531166530.7104] sup-iface[0x563a1b190d00,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason 3)
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.7156] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.7173] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.7175] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  9 13:02:10 thinkpad NetworkManager[855]: <info>  [1531166530.8152] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

I've tried looking up "Reason 3" with little avail to a solution. I've tried supplying my username and password in the settings file and this hasn't worked either. It looks like it's trying to use MSCHAPV2. There's no setting for none. I tried MD5 and GTC as well. Those didn't work. I tried entering none in a settings file I found on a site but it didn't work and somewhere else someone said that doing that is an invalid setting anyway.

I'm stuck as to any further ideas. It works on android. Any chance of printing out the settings it's using somehow to connect?

(I put XXXX in place of possibly identifying info, but it appears correct for the actual names in the logs for my site)

Any help is appreciated, even a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot downgrade wpa\_supplicant to fix Wifi connection to a corporate network (WPA2) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w)

Comment: So this isn't exactly an answer so I won't put an answer here, however, for some reason the way NetworkManager on Ubuntu/Debian works doesn't deal with the no certificate issue and causes a repeated dialog asking for a password to pop up. However, Fedora 29 and Arch based distros (as of the date of this comment) works with the same exact settings. Oddly fedora 28 and before does *not* work. There is clearly some way the configuration is on Arch/Fedora>=29 that is different from Ubuntu's. I tried copying Fedora's `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ .nmconnection` file but it doesn't work.