# Unable to connect with wifi to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

Can some one help me on this, below is the ssid config.

```
[connection]
id=BM-CorpNet
uuid=bf3989d5-6b54-4a27-95be-92e715350873
type=wifi
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address=70:A6:CC:3D:FB:3A
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=BM-CorpNet

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=pwd;
identity=test.xxx
pass=xxx

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Comment: logs> ssid is enable we are trying to authenticate with Active Directory Credentials

Nov  2 18:57:32 idc-dev02 wpa_supplicant[956]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:27:90:47:66:0e reason=3 locally_generated=1
Nov  2 18:57:32 idc-dev02 wpa_supplicant[956]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="BM-CorpNet" auth_failures=2 duration=26 reason=AUTH_FA

Comment: If this is more info for the question please edit the question and add it there. Not as a comment. Comments are where the person trying to help you asks questions to get more details to aid in assisting.

Comment: what exactly are you doing (what did you click/type/etc)? What do you see that makes you think you aren't connected to the wifi?

Comment: my issue got fixed thanks

Comment: this setting worked >> https://askubuntu.com/questions/929680/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap-network

I was trying to connect wifi with active directory credentials since we have integrated our wifi to AD..