# how to connect to WPA2 enterprise WiFi in Ubuntu Core Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ubuntu-core

I'm using NetworkManager in Ubuntu Core to my WPA2 personal WiFi and it works. Now I want to connect to WPA2 802.1x WiFi in office premise. Is it possible using NetworkManager? If yes can anyone guide me how to do it?

The solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c) doesn't really work in Ubuntu Core because it doesn't allow to create files in the /etc/NetworkManager/ path due to read-only file system.

Comment: Tthanks for the comment. I did try to make it writable but failed miserably. In the end i found a solution using nmcli console. I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem in regards to this question. Here's how I did it in Ubuntu Core using NetworkManager nmcli console:

```
$ network-manager.nmcli connection edit type 802-11-wireless
nmcli> goto 802-11-wireless
nmcli 802-11-wireless> set ssid <your_ssid>
nmcli 802-11-wireless> back
nmcli> goto 802-11-wireless-security
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> set key-mgmt wpa-eap
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> set auth-alg open
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> back
nmcli> goto 802-1x
nmcli 802-1x> set eap peap
nmcli 802-1x> set identity <your_identity>
nmcli 802-1x> set password <your_password>
nmcli 802-1x> set phase2-auth mschapv2
nmcli 802-1x> back
nmcli> verify
nmcli> save
Saving the connection with 'autoconnect=yes'. That might result in an immediate activation of the connection.
Do you still want to save? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Connection 'wifi' (20e7bab0-6780-45a7-b650-eafb28e7912a) successfully saved.
```

Ubuntu should try to connect by now and you might be disconnected if you're currently ssh-ed in. Just ssh again with the new IP address (if you use IP).

Points of reference:

1. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/nm-settings.5.html
2. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man7/nmcli-examples.7.html