# 18.04 Can connect to dorm WiFi, but lost connection to campus WiFi

Tags: wireless

On a System76 Darter Pro laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, the WiFi at my school suddenly stopped working, but I can still connect to my dorm WiFi.

I recently changed my password and then when I had to reverify my information to sign in it asked for a domain which was odd. I'm able to connect to my dorm wifi still because the password for that wifi hasn't had to be put back in. The wifi will attempt to connect when I press "no CA certificate is required" but it never works.

If it makes any difference I'm attending ASU, we have 2 wifi's that are possible to use; the ASU wifi, and eduroam wifi. They both use PEAP wifi, I am very new to any network connections. I have tried EVERYTHING I could find on google and asked in all geo-stories, went to the tech service center and they didn't know what to do. I tried using the certification that ASU recommended to use and that didn't work. It's getting to the point of affecting my school work so please if you have ANY suggestions please let me know!

Comment: If you boot from a LiveUSB, are you able to connect to the campus WiFi?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA\_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c)

Comment: This may be your solution. Please let us know if it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Also, people report that the line in the file that needs to be deleted (in the highest voted answer) is not present in newer versions of Ubuntu. You can try adding the line to the file but make the line say `false` instead of `true`. There are also other answers to the same question that involve different methods and one of these other answers may be your solution.

Comment: Another thing you could try to edit the old configuration file for your network (if it is still present) in your `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory and just change the old password to the new password or if there is no line for a password you may need to add one: `password=mypassword` (with your real password of course) and you may have to delete the line: `password-flags=1` if it is present. Also, it may help to delete any additional configuration files for that same network (if they exist) which are also located in your `/etc/NetworkManager/system-conections` directory.

Comment: I've tried all of these and nothing worked... The only thing that changed after trying to add an SSID file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections was that now it says I don't have a wifi adapter connected.