# After upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 does't works

Tags: wireless, 22.04

How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like WOW FI - FASTWEB

I tried all the stuff in these links:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1405397/47501/

[WPA2 wifi refuses to connect after upgrade to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404059/)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267

[How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/)

[wpa_supplicant/OpenSSL connection problems after 22.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407603/)

[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/)

but nothing works for me

the only way I found is downgrade to ubuntu 21.10

this made me crazy because now 21.10 is old and no longer update are going to it

with the same computer and 21.10 the WPA2 works

this is the wireless-info file (the essential part, I hope)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Aug 2022 18:26 CEST +0200

Booted last: 11 Aug 2022 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 12 10:30:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:1360]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5e0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd VGA WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 047d:1022 Kensington Orbit Optical
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

ath10k_pci             49152  0
acer_wmi               28672  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
ath10k_core           589824  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
mac80211             1228800  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              958464  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
wmi                    32768  2 acer_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  53248  2 acer_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet <IP address>/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet <IP address>/24 brd <IP address> scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 79467sec preferred_lft 79467sec
    inet6 <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet <IP address>/24 brd <IP address>scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 83659sec preferred_lft 83659sec
    inet6 <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FASTWEB-A56F58"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.54 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC4]>
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=26 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:337   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via <IP address> dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100
default via <IP address> dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600
<IP address>/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000
<IP address>/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src <IP address> metric 100
<IP address>/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src <IP address>metric 600

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']

nameserver <IP address>
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         620       1  0 Aug07 ?        00:01:18 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-43-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Connessione via cavo 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       <HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         <IP address>/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            <IP address>
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = <IP address>/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = <IP address>, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             <IP address>
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name = lan
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1660314680
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = my-name
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = <HEX>::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.DNS[1]:                             <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>
IP6.SEARCHES[1]:                        lan
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = lan
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   <HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX> | Connessione via cavo 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-43-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:03:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     FASTWEB-A56F58
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       <HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/18
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     6 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         <IP address>/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            <IP address>
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = <IP address>/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = <IP address>/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = <IP address>, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             <IP address>
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name = lan
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1660318872
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = my-name
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = <IP address>
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.DNS[1]:                             <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>
IP6.SEARCHES[1]:                        lan
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = lan
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = <HEX>::<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>:<HEX>
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   <HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX>-<HEX> | FASTWEB-A56F58

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/8
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                      BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY     ACTIVE  IN-USE
WOW FI - FASTWEB          <MAC 'WOW FI - FASTWEB' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  130 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█  WPA2 802.1X  no
FASTWEB-A56F58            <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  130 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2         no

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FASTWEB-A56F58.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FASTWEB-A56F58 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=FASTWEB-A56F58
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WOW FI - FASTWEB.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WOW FI - FASTWEB | type=wifi
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=WOW FI - FASTWEB
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

global
country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (5945 - 6425 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0
country 99: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5140 - 5360 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5460 - 5860 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel ...
          Current Frequency:5.54 GHz (Channel 108)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      3   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      7   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.26 GHz (Channel 52)
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.54 GHz (Channel 108)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.56 GHz (Channel 112)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)

wlp3s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FASTWEB-A56F58"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000157cbb08ed0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6600ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'WOW FI - FASTWEB' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WOW FI - FASTWEB"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000157cbb09d93
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6596ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       5.15.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_core
vermagic:       5.15.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)
parm:           coredump_mask:Bitfield of what to include in firmware crash file (ulong)
parm:           fw_diag_log:Diag based fw log debugging (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       5.15.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
coredump_mask: 3
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
fw_diag_log: N
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[362684.531791] wlp3s0: authenticate with <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC4]>
[362684.560439] wlp3s0: send auth to <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC4]> (try 1/3)
[362684.561136] wlp3s0: authenticated
[362684.567644] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC4]> (try 1/3)
[362684.569488] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC4]> (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=1)
[362684.572120] wlp3s0: associated
[362684.572261] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[362684.572263] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[362684.572265] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[362684.572266] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[362684.572267] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[362684.572268] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[362684.572269] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country element
[362684.606547] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'FASTWEB-A56F58' [AC4]>
[362684.639813] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
########## wireless info END ############
```

but WPA2 still not works

Comment: You can't add sources from another release. This isn't a solution and you will break your system doing this. You need to remove the sources that aren't for your release.

Comment: Hi Nmath You mean for impish.list ? they are for debian ? was my doubt thanks. I remove it. But still not works